# Unable to use IIS ADSI Provider after IIS installation if ADsOpenObject was called before install

Tags: c#, iis, adsi

My .Net application actively uses Active Directory and installs IIS if its absent.
If IIS wasn't installed on application startup and any of Active Directory-related methods were called then IIS ADSI Provider stills unavailable after IIS installation (after application restart it becomes available).
Unfortunately i cannot change the operations sequence, so it must be "**use AD -> install IIS -> use IIS ADSI provider -> use AD**"

My steps-to-reproduce code (not real) is:

```
        using (Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
        {
        }
        // IIS install here
        using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1"))
        {
            var options = entry.Options; // exception here
        }
```

Changed sequence works fine:

```
        // IIS install here
        using (Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
        {
        }
        using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1"))
        {
            var options = entry.Options;
        }
```

Using Reflector i have found that it is enough to call [ADsOpenObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772238%28VS.85%29.aspx) once to make IIS ADSI provider unavailable after IIS installation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object ldapPPObject = GetAdsObject("LDAP://TestDomain.local/RootDSE");
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ldapPPObject);
        // IIS install here
        object iisPPObject = GetAdsObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1"); // exception here
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(iisPPObject);
    }
    private static object GetAdsObject(string path)
    {
        Guid iid = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-c000-000000000046");
        object ppObject;
        if (IntADsOpenObject(path, null, null, 193, ref iid, out ppObject) != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("ADsOpenObject failed");
        }
        return ppObject;
    }
    [DllImport("activeds.dll", EntryPoint = "ADsOpenObject", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int IntADsOpenObject(string path, string userName, string password, int flags, [In, Out] ref Guid iid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppObject);
}
```

I have tried to create separate app domain and place there code that uses IIS but this try was failed too.

How can i force AD reinitialization to get IIS ADSI provider available after IIS installation?

Answer (score 0):

.Net had nothing to do with the problem.
The following c++ code fails too:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IADs *pObject;
    HRESULT hr;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://TestDomain.local/RootDSE", NULL, NULL, 193, IID_IADs, (void**) &pObject);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pObject->Release();
    }
    // install iis here
    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1", NULL, NULL, 193, IID_IADs, (void**) &pObject);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) // not succeeded
    {
        pObject->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

But the trouble still need to be solved somehow...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the ADSI provider working again after the call to ADsOpenObject. Sorry.